# Writing LDAP query filter

Tags: filter, ldap, jndi, ldap-query

I have trouble writing a filter for LDAP query.

I have two object classes - Person and Service. Database consists of a number of Persons, each having zero or more services as children. Each person has an identifier, personNumber attribute. I want to select several persons and all their services given person numbers. Is it possible to do so in one query?

For example, if we have the following set of objects:

```
                personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=1,personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=2,personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
                personNumber=2,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=3,personNumber=2,ou=root,o=org
                personNumber=3,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=4,personNumber=3,ou=root,o=org
```

, is it possible, given person numbers 1 and 2, to retrieve these objects:

```
                personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=1,personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=2,personNumber=1,ou=root,o=org
                personNumber=2,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=3,personNumber=2,ou=root,o=org
```

but not these:

```
                personNumber=3,ou=root,o=org
serviceNumber=4,personNumber=3,ou=root,o=org
```

, *using one query only*? It is an example; it is possible to have more than two identifiers to load. They are not known a priori.

Also, is there a way to specify that attribute value should be in some collection of values, like `IN (..)` clause in SQL, other than generating big `(|(a=..)(a=..)(a=..)..)` filter?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question. If you find persons nodes for each found node you have to retrieve the children (services in your case). LDAP doesn't do a rollup. The second part is probably no, according to this spec: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4515

Comment: @rene I have added an example to the question on what I want to do.

Comment: That makes it more clear. Does person have (multivalue) attribute that links it to service or is the only relation the ldap hierarchy? In the latter case you can't have such an result.

Comment: @rene No, it is only LDAP hierarchy. Thank you. I'll mark your answer as accepted if you make it proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If person doesn't have a multivalued attribute holding the service there is no way this can be returned in one ldapsearch. You'll need at least a two stage rocket: first select person, for each person check on childnodes.

AFAIK there is no IN operator in LDAP filters. The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#page-3) is clear about that. So you're stuck with your tedious (|(a=s1)(a=s2)(a=s3)...) construct.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No, per RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254,  there is NO such filter.If the IN list is very large and you have lots of people in ldap, you need write a simple paged query to get all results using (objectClass=Person) filter, and filter the result after retrial. if your code is written in Java, you can checkout  [unboundid LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/SimplePagedResultsControl.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, we're using Java, but, unfortunately, I cannot use anything except JNDI facilities.

Comment: please check out [link] ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html )